# What is the guard statement on this loop? - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a refactor of some older `js` and came across this loop:

```
var components = str.split('.');
var previousComponent = global;

for (var i = 0, component; component = components[i]; i++) {
  if (typeof previousComponent[component] === "undefined") {
    previousComponent[component] = {};
  }
  previousComponent = previousComponent[component];
}
```

I do not see how the guard statement says that this look ends.  Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: `component = components[i]` "returns" `component`. It is undefined when `i>components.length`.

Comment: That makes sense.  Make it into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: The fact you had to ask tells me it is ugly code.

Answer (score 4):

The condition `component = components[i]` "returns" component. It is undefined when `i == components.length`, therefore ending the loop.

As Jim Cote mentioned, another condition is if `str` has 2 dots together, then component can be an empty string, and also end the loop.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is about when the loop ends, it ends when `i` is equal to the length of the array.

The condition part of your for statement is `component = components[i]` which assigns the value in `components[i]` to `component` and then *returns* that value to calling context - which is your for loop.

At the end of the array, when `i === components.length`, `components[i]` will be `undefined` which is not truthy, and hence breaks the loop.

Comment: Is this common in `js`?  I haven't seen this in many codebases.  It seems like we are giving up clarity to save a few characters.

Comment: Note that if one of the components is an empty string, the loop with end prematurely.

Comment: @jhamm common or not I don't think it's very readable. Readability should be more important, use optimizers to save characters.

Comment: String splits can still produce empty components.

Comment: @techfoobar yes but as JimCote says if the string is e.g. `something..like..that`  it will stop earlier. And thats the problem about such a condition.

Comment: @t.niese - Yeah, i was thinking in terms of a char by char split (i.e. `.split('')` - and hence the confusion arose. With any other character based split, empty parts are definitely to be expected.

Comment: @jhamm - Frankly, i haven't seen this usage much. I would rather write readable code and pass it via an optimizer like closure or uglify.

Comment: @JimCote - Perhaps thats the intention of the original code. Stop at end of string or when you find 2 consecutive dots.

Comment: @techfoobar And I think thats exactly the problem with that code, it is not clear if the author was award of this, or if it is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop itself:

```
for (var i = 0, component; component = components[i]; i++) {
```

Note the part that says `component = components[i]`.

This is **not** the equality comparison that we would typically find here, because it is `=`, not `==` or `===`.

When the RHS (`components[i]`) is *falsy*, the loop will break.